# Make bash alias to simplifid commands and getting Not found Error

Tags: php, laravel, bash, macos, alias

for our web application we use useful commands such as :

```sh
php artiasn
php artisan serve
composer update
php artisan view:clear
```

and now i want to make alias for them into `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias ps ="php artisan"
alias serve="php artisan serve"
alias cu="composer update"
alias vc="php artisan view:clear"
```

now when i try to reload the file by using `source ~/.bash_profile` i get this error:

```
.bash_profile:1: php artisan not found
```

I thought i should use `cd` for change to the directory before. I got the error again. for example:

```
alias ps ="cd /User/myname/Desktop/project php artisan"
```

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ you right, after successfully reload the file. when i try to use alias commands i get `zsh: command not found: vc` error

Comment: for Windows GitBash my issue was the single quote which copied from a webpage and I replaces the quotes with my keyboard singlequotes like -  alias pa='php artisan' before it was like alias pa=’php artisan’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correctly in the docs the space in between:

`alias ps =`

Should be:

`alias ps=`

Also instead of using `source` there is a shorter way with `. ~/.zshrc`

Per memory you have to reference where you have PHP. You can run `which php` to get the location if you cannot access from  `/usr/bin/php`.

Can also try `alias ps ="/usr/bin/php artisan"`

Comment: putting aliases into `~/.zshrc` file and reload it, resolved my problem. please update your post and let me to accept that

Comment: It might be better to use `#!/usr/bin/env php` rather than pointing to `/usr/bin/php` directly, depending on your needs. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517/802469